# How to invoke a java process remotely using Jsch

Tags: java, linux, bash, remote-server, jsch

I tried to connect remotely and execute below command Using Jsch .

```
cd /home/server/;chmod 777 myjar.jar;chmod 777 myjar.sh;./myjar.sh
```

while executing using Jsch the below command is executed

```
cd /home/server/;chmod 777 myjar.jar;chmod 777 myjar.sh;
```

but ./myjar.sh shows error like " **bash java cannot find symbol**"

but the remote location has java installed , and if executed in remote location directly the error is not shown

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would connect your commands using &&, in case one fails. In your example above, one command's failure won't terminate your subsequent execution

Comment: Can we see your myjar.sh ? And/or execute it with a -x option to show each line as it executes

Comment: I suggest you run `set`, once while logged into the remote server, once using JSch -- and compare the output (perhaps with `diff`). I expect you to find differences e.g. in `$PATH` or `$LIBPATH` which may account for this.

Comment: @BrianAgnew myjar.sh contains **java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -jar myjar.jar -A192.xx.xx.x -P10205**

Comment: @slim I will check that.

Comment: `chmod 777 myjar.jar` is obsolete.  `chmod 777 myjar.sh` adds excesive access rights to edit this file for everyone. Probably you just need to do `chmod a+x myjar.sh`. Please provide results of command: `cd /home/server/; which java; echo "$PATH"`

Comment: @sim I have checked as per your suggestion both returns different output.`echo $PATH` through Jsch and Server .

Comment: @Kamil `cd /home/server/; which java; echo "$PATH"` gives output as no java in (\usr\local\bin)

Comment: So you have incorrecly installed java or PATH variable is set incorrectly when you connect to your server. Maybe you can force it to "see" your java using something like this `cd /home/server/;chmod a+x myjar.sh; export PATH="/usr/lib/where_your_java_is_located:$PATH";./myjar.sh`

Comment: @Kamil In server I am able to use the `which java` , and it is also installed correctly in the server , problem is that the remote location , java installed path is not know . in advance ,  because each time we may be connecting to different remote servers.

Comment: So your remote servers probably dont have java installed. You should put java there, and then try to run your scripts.